# Postgres query is fast from inside container but slow when called from adjacent FastAPI/SQLAlchemy container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

Some background:

I have a relatively simple docker-compose setup with a backend python-based service that has FastAPI and SQLAlchemy running, which connects to a postgres container that houses a decent (but not crazy) amount of data.

All of the queries I run from `psql` directly inside the postgres container are as fast as expected (<1s each), but when I run the same exact queries (massaged into their python/SQLAlchemy counterparts and verified to be the same by printing the SQL it compiles down to), it can take up to 1 minute (!!!) to get the results through SQLAlchemy up to my FastAPI server. The time it takes to return results seems to scale with how many rows are being returned (i.e. returning 2000 rows is ~10x slower than returning 200 rows).

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql+psycopg2://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: /bin/bash -c 'alembic upgrade head && python main.py'
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

(the environment variables come from a .env file).

the query in question in sql is basically:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, ..., column_10

FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
WHERE table_1.id = param_1 ORDER BY table_2.id;
```

or in python:

```
db.query(
    column_1,
    column_2,
    ...,
    column_10,
) \
    .filter(table_1.id == param_1).join(table_2) \
    .order_by(table_2.id).all()
```

have I messed something up? or is this a bad docker practice where passing data between containers over the docker network is slow and I should put my database inside the same container as my python server?

Comment: use auto_explain to capture the plan for the slow query, and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to do so for the fast manual one.

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean—they're the same query but called from a different number of layers removed from the actual database. also I'm new to the finer details of databases, so do you mean that I should set auto_explain to true somewhere in SQLAlchemy? And then manually run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) MANUAL_QUERY` where MANUAL_QUERY is my select/from/where in the original question?

Comment: For the run from inside psql, just put `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` in front of the query text when you execute it.  To capture the plan for the other one, you configure PostgreSQL to use the auto_explain extension  to log the plans of slow queries.  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html

Comment: not sure if it doesn't log anything because it's not a slow query, but I'm not seeing anything in `/var/log/postgresql` after setting that in the config and reloading the service. but when running it manually with `EXPLAIN`, I'm pretty sure the query itself isn't the problem:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 Planning Time: 0.163 ms
 Execution Time: 232.010 ms